# Hall light flickers when bedroom ceiling fan is on

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan, recessed-lighting

I came across a house today, that someone installed new ceiling fans in. Before, they were fans with dimmer switches for the lights. The new ceiling fans are led non-dimmable.

The power is shared with the room lighting and the hall light.

The hall light is a recessed can light. It works fine until the ceiling fan in the bedroom is turned on, then it begins to lightly flicker.

Any ideas?
All ideas and support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about how you "came across a house today", yet you know enough about it to know that someone recently installed new ceiling fans. Maybe English isn't your first language - "came across a house today" implies that this is the first time you've ever seen it, and in this context, that is confusing.

Comment: @FreeMan Sounds like the OP is house hunting and either has a good realtor who knows the back story to the house or the current owner showed the house to the OP.